# Dynamic creation of large html table in javascript performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I have an application which is used for data analysis and I'm having a few performance issues with the creation of the table. The data is extracted from documents and it is important that all data is presented on one page (pagination is not an option unfortunately).

Using jQuery, I make an ajax request to the server to retrieve the data. On completion of the request, I pass the data to an output function. The output function loops through the data array using a for loop and concatenating the rows to a variable. Once the looping is complete, the variable containing the table is then appended to an existing div on the page and then I go on to bind events to the table for working with the data.

With a small set of data (~1000-2000 rows) it works relatively good but some of the data sets contain upwards of 10,000 rows which causes Firefox to either crash and close or become unresponsive.

My question is, is there a better way to accomplish what I am doing?

Here's some code:

```
//This function gets called by the interface with an id to retrieve a document
function loadDocument(id){
    $.ajax({
        method: "get",
        url: "ajax.php",
        data: {action:'loadDocument',id: id},
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: true,
        beforeSend: function(){
            if($("#loading").dialog('isOpen') != true){
                //Display the loading dialog
                $("#loading").dialog({
                    modal: true
                });
            }//end if
        },//end beforesend
        success: function(result){
            if(result.Error == undefined){
                outputDocument(result, id);
            }else{
                <handle error code>
            }//end if
            if($('#loading').dialog('isOpen') == true){
                //Close the loading dialog
                $("#loading").dialog('close');
            }//end if
        }//end success
    });//end ajax
};//end loadDocument();


//Output document to screen
function outputDocument(data, doc_id){

    //Begin document output
    var rows = '<table>';
    rows += '<thead>';
    rows += '<tr>';
    rows += '<th>ID</th>';
    rows += '<th>Status</th>';
    rows += '<th>Name</th>';
    rows += '<th>Actions</th>';
    rows += '<th>Origin</th>';
    rows += '</tr>';
    rows += '</thead>';
    rows += '<tbody>';

    for(var i in data){
        var recordId = data[i].id;
        rows += '<tr id="' + recordId + '" class="' + data[i].status + '">';
        rows += '<td width="1%" align="center">' + recordId + '</td>';
        rows += '<td width="1%" align="center"><span class="status" rel="' + recordId + '"><strong>' + data[i].status + '</strong></span></td>';
        rows += '<td width="70%"><span class="name">' + data[i].name + '</span></td>';
        rows += '<td width="2%">';
        rows += '<input type="button" class="failOne" rev="' + recordId + '" value="F">';
        rows += '<input type="button" class="promoteOne" rev="' + recordId + '" value="P">';
        rows += '</td>';
        rows += '<td width="1%">' + data[i].origin + '</td>';
        rows += '</tr>';
    }//end for

    rows += '</tbody>';
    rows += '</table>';
    $('#documentRows').html(rows);
```

I was initially using a jQuery each loop but switched to the for loop which shaved off some ms.

I thought of using something like google gears to try offloading some of the processing (if that's possible in this scenario).

Any thoughts?

Comment: Show the first hundred and than use timers or workers to build the others. Remeber that the browser is single threaded. While js is executing, the browser is unresponsive. Use event delegation.

Comment: Use virtual scrolling http://nexts.github.io/Clusterize.js/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

joinHi,

The rendering is a problem, but there is also a problem with concatenating so many strings inside the loop, especially once the string gets very large. It would probably be best to put the strings into individual elements of an array then finally use "join" to create the huge string in one fell swoop. e.g.

```
var r = new Array();
var j = -1, recordId;
r[++j] =  '<table><thead><tr><th>ID</th><th>Status</th><th>Name</th><th>Actions</th><th>Origin</th></tr></thead><tbody>'; 
for (var i in data){
    var d = data[i];
    recordId = d.id;
    r[++j] = '<tr id="';
    r[++j] = recordId;
    r[++j] = '" class="';
    r[++j] = d.status;
    r[++j] = '"><td width="1%" align="center">';
    r[++j] = recordId;
    r[++j] = '</td><td width="1%" align="center"><span class="status" rel="';
    r[++j] = recordId;
    r[++j] = '"><strong>';
    r[++j] = d.status;
    r[++j] = '</strong></span></td><td width="70%"><span class="name">';
    r[++j] = d.name;
    r[++j] = '</span></td><td width="2%"><input type="button" class="failOne" rev="';
    r[++j] = recordId;
    r[++j] = '" value="F"><input type="button" class="promoteOne" rev="';
    r[++j] = recordId;
    r[++j] = '" value="P"></td><td width="1%">';
    r[++j] = d.origin;
    r[++j] = '</td></tr>';
}
r[++j] = '</tbody></table>';
$('#documentRows').html(r.join(''));
```

Also, I would use the array indexing method shown here, rather than using "push" since, for all browsers except Google Chrome it is faster, according to [this article](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2010/10/15/javascript-array-performance.html).

Comment: You may squeeze a bit more performance out by specifying the length of the array when you construct it e.g. var r = new Array(data.length*19+2)

Comment: Also, you include the width as a percentage in the '<td>' tags in the table. That a lot of duplicate specifications. Why not put the width value just on the '<th>' elements at the top. similar with the 'align="center"' specifications. That way you'll save the engine having to look at every individual data cell for its width and cut down on the string size.

Comment: Nice use of ++j, I'd advise fixing the loop definition for an extra bit of performance.

Comment: Digiguru, thanks I come from a 'C' and Perl programming background and would always advocate using the '++', '--' pre- post-fix operators and the '+=', '-=', '*=' operators for clarity.

Comment: I'm using this code in a virtually paged table, I find I'm getting a little bit more performance by not recreating the entire table every time. I just set the HTML of the tbody. This also has the nice side effect that the headers remain visible while the data is loading.

Answer (score 4):

Displaying that many rows is causing the browser's *rendering engine* to slow down, not the JavaScript engine. Unfortunately there's not a lot you can do about that.

The best solution is to just not display so many rows at the same time, either through pagination, or virtual scrolling.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm not sure if virtual scrolling will be an option but. I think I'll try loading x records at a time as per @jasssonpet suggestion. I know it's expensive to append records to an existing table, I wonder if this will just move the bottleneck to there instead though?

Answer (score 2):

The way you are building your string will cause massive amounts of garbage collection.

As the string gets longer and longer the javascript engine has to keep allocating larger buffers and discarding the old ones. Eventually it will not be able to allocate sufficient memory without recycling the remains of all the old strings.

This problem gets worse as the string grows longer.

Instead try adding new elements to the DOM one at a time using the [jQuery manipulation API](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/)

Also consider only rendering what is visible and implement your own scrolling.

Comment: This first part of your response is what I was looking for. I don't know much about the javascript engines internals but I figured appending all that data to a variable has to be causing some sort of issue. 

Is there a better way to accomplish this without appending the data to the table and resetting the variable. I tried appending the row to the table during each loop but, it went from like 5,000ms to 132,000ms for a doc with 7200 records.

Comment: To be honest I think the best answer is just not to display that amount of data. It's hard to imagine a situation in which I would want to scroll through 10000 rows - or even 1000.

Comment: Makes as much sense to me too!! I don't want to say what the app is but, the data needs to be displayed in order and as a whole for spotting trends etc. I'm trying to come up with some sort of solution to get around this but it's very visual and hard to explain, you'd have to see it :). Thanks so much for your response, it's pointed me in a new direction!

Comment: Did you try building the entire table in-memory _before_ inserting it into the DOM?  That should save the browser from having to reflow and repaint every time you add a row.

Comment: Building a huge table using jQuery manipulation api is really slow though... If it's performance he's after the string is the way to go (albeit not as elegant).

Answer (score 1):

You can do couple of things to increase the performance:

1. your **rows** variable is getting bigger and bigger so, don't store the html in one variable. solution can be `$.each()` function and each function you append the element into DOM. But this is minor adjustment.
2. Html generating is good, but you can try DOM creating and appending. Like `$('<tr></tr>')`.
3. And finally, this will solve your problem for sure : use multiple ajax call in the first ajax call collect how many data is available and fetch approximately 1,000 or may be more data. And use other calls to collect remaining data. If you want, you can use synchronous call or Asynchronous calls wisely.

But try to avoid storing the value. Your DOM size will be huge but it should work on moder browsers and forget about IE6.

@fuel37 : Example

```
function outputDocumentNew(data, doc_id) {
    //Variable DOM's
    var rowSample = $('<tr></tr>').addClass('row-class');
    var colSample = $('<td></td>').addClass('col-class');
    var spanSample = $('<span></span>').addClass('span-class');
    var inputButtonSample = $('<input type="button"/>').addClass('input-class');

    //DOM Container 
    var container = $('#documentRows');
    container.empty().append('<table></table>');

    //Static part
    var head = '<thead>\
                <tr>\
                    <th width="1%" align="center">ID</th>\
                    <th width="1%" align="center">Status</th>\
                    <th width="70%">Name</th>\
                    <th width="2%">Actions</th>\
                    <th width="1%">Origin</th>\
                </tr>\
                </thead>';
    container.append(head);

    var body = $('<tbody></tbody>');
    container.append(body);

    //Dynamic part
    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
        var _this = this;

        //DOM Manupulation
        var row = rowSample.clone();

        //Actions
        var inpFailOne = inputButtonSample.clone().val('F').attr('rev', _this.id).addClass('failOne').click(function (e) {
            //do something when click the button.
        });
        var inpPromoteOne = inputButtonSample.clone().val('P').attr('rev', _this.id).addClass('promoteOne').click(function (e) {
            //do something when click the button.
        });

        row
        .append(colSample.clone().append(_this.id))
        .append(colSample.clone().append(spanSample.colne().addClass('status').append(_this.status)))
        .append(colSample.clone().append(spanSample.colne().addClass('name').append(_this.name)))
        .append(colSample.clone().append(inpFailOne).append(inpPromoteOne))
        .append(colSample.clone().append(_this.origin));

        body.append(row);
    });
}
```

in this process you need to create & maintain id's or classes for manipulation. You have the control to bind events and manipulate each elements there.

Comment: Can you provide an example of #2? I've never created elements in this way before.

Answer (score 0):

Answering to get formatting

What happens if you do

```
for(var i in data){
    var record = data[i];
    var recordId = record.id;
    rows += '<tr id="' + recordId + '" class="' + record.status + '">';
    rows += '<td width="1%" align="center">' + recordId + '</td>';
    rows += '<td width="1%" align="center"><span class="status" rel="' + recordId + '"><strong>' + data[i].status + '</strong></span></td>';
    rows += '<td width="70%"><span class="name">' + record.name + '</span></td>';
    rows += '<td width="2%">';
    rows += '<input type="button" class="failOne" rev="' + recordId + '" value="F">';
    rows += '<input type="button" class="promoteOne" rev="' + recordId + '" value="P">';
    rows += '</td>';
    rows += '<td width="1%">' + record.origin + '</td>';
    rows += '</tr>';
}//end for
```

Comment: then I agree on Box9's pagination suggestion

Comment: With that amount of data, I'd suggest using some sort of string buffer. Otherwise the program will be unnecesarily slowly - see http://www.softwaresecretweapons.com/jspwiki/javascriptstringconcatenation for details.

Answer (score 0):

Per others suggestions (I'm not reputable enough to comment yet, sorry!), you might try the [TableSorter plugin](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-pager.html) to handle only displaying a usable amount of data at a time.

I don't know how it fares at very high numbers of rows, but their example data is 1000 rows or so.

This wouldn't help with JS performance but would keep the burden off the browser renderer.

Comment: I've tried this in another instance and it seems to puke after about 2000 records as well.

Answer (score 0):

Could try this...

[Improve Loops](http://robertnyman.com/2008/04/11/javascript-loop-performance/)

[Improve String Concat](http://www.bloggingdeveloper.com/post/JavaScript-Array-Join-vs-String-Concatenation-Avoid-String-Concatenations-Major-Hit-on-Performance.aspx)

```
var tmpLst = [];

for (var i=0, il=data.length; i<il; i++) {
    var record = data[i];
    var recordId = record.id;

    tmpLst.push('<tr id="');
    tmpLst.push(recordId); 
    tmpLst.push('" class="'); 
    tmpLst.push(record.status);
    tmpLst.push('">');
    tmpLst.push('<td width="1%" align="center">');

...ect...


}
rows += tmpLst.join('');
```

This might squeeze an extra bit of performance...

```
var lstReset = i * lstReset.length;
tmpLst[lstReset + 1]='<tr id="';
tmpLst[lstReset + 2]=recordId; 
tmpLst[lstReset + 3]='" class="';
```