# Best way to inject a html row template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance

I have a large amount of datarows in a json file which i load via ajax.

I then create quite some html code containing some of the data for each row like this.

```
var gl = $("#gameslist");
$.each(DATA.games, function(index, value) {
  gl.append( '<div>... lots of html code here ... '+value.somedata+'</div>');
}
```

this seems to be quite slow, especially on the mobile safari browser. are there any tricks or jquery plugins to speed this up?

edit: as requested, here is the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: "../games.json"
})
.done(function(gamesjson){
    DATA = gamesjson;
    buildPage(); // this one is calling the above code
  })
.fail(function(){
    console.log("games.json error");
  })
;
```

Comment: I don't know how jQuery does it, but `insertAdjecentHTML` in pure Javascript may be significantly faster.

Comment: Don't use [.each](http://jsperf.com/browser-diet-jquery-each-vs-for-loop) and use a for loop instead?

Comment: See if this helps
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361810/fast-way-to-dynamically-fill-table-with-data-from-json-in-javascript

Comment: Are you sure it's this code that's slow?  What have you done to pinpoint the problem? Could you show us this code in conjunction with the AJAX call that (presumably) calls this?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker this is pretty much the only code on the page, thats why i believe this is the reason. also the data is quite huge. there are about 350 rows having 30 values each.

Comment: @RGraham: ok, but why do you think .each is slower than a for loop?

Comment: @clamp That's not really that big -- The reason I ask is that it can't load the data until the Ajax call completes (which is why I'd like to see your code with the Ajax call that calls it), and if that Ajax call takes a long time that would make it appear like this is the issue, when it's not.

Comment: @clamp See the link in my previous comment from jsperf. Might not make a huge difference, but there certainly seems to be a pattern there

Comment: @Anand: thanks, this one looks good too! will try it!

Comment: Hey it would be nice if you find some conclusive way, then could you please test (with timers) and post what you did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's slow cause `DATA.games` can be huge, and you're calling (ok, a cached) `$("#gameslist")`
 but you're using `append()` for every loop iteration.

To speed up things, create a variable that will hold the string representation of your HTML (containing DIVs and the data) , than inside a `for` loop append to string using `+=` than once the loop is over append only once to your `$("#gameslist")`

**Here I created a *[live demo](http://jsbin.com/UqoKewA/4/edit)* to show you the drastic difference:**

*For only **1000** iterations and a HTML complexity of only **4** elements/iteration*
Using `.append()` inside loop                  = **~100ms**
Using `.append()` only once (after loop)  = **~30ms**

> Both tests in `for loop`... That was all just about using `.append()` in the right way / place.

Now back about the **differences in speed** between `$.each` and the good old `for`, I've found an interesting jsPerf:

http://jsperf.com/browser-diet-jquery-each-vs-for-loop <sub>(**Note:** higher is better)</sub>

---

<sup>***Memo:*** Test snippet:</sup>

```
var initialTime = new Date().getTime();

for(var i=0; i<10000; i++){
   // your code
}

console.log( new Date.getTime() - initialTime ); // ms
```

Answer (score 3):

You're modifying the DOM on every iteration, if you only modify the DOM once instead it will speed it up considerably. Use a fragment to hold the elements while iterating, then append them all at once at the end :

```
var gl = document.createDocumentFragment();

$.each(DATA.games, function(index, value) {
    var div  = document.createElement('div'),
        text = document.createTextNode('... lots of html code here ... '+value.somedata);

    gl.appendChild(div.appendChild(text));
}

$("#gameslist").append(gl);
```