# Dynamically creating table using jQuery. Table is not getting displayed

Tags: html, jquery, datatables

I am new to jQuery. I have to query 2 web services and based on an attribute value in first web service I have to query the next one and populate the result in a table using data from both web services.

Please have a look at the code at http://jsfiddle.net/ykPXZ/2/ . I am trying to append the table data to a div having id="tableData". I am getting the data from the web service and I have checked the console logs to see whether the data is getting appended to the variable tableDataA and it is getting appended but I am not to display the data on the web page. Somehow it is getting rewritten or deleted.

Please tell me if this is the best approach for solving this problem. Please suggest a better approach to it.

Thanks.

EDIT: Dynamically generated table is showing 23 rows instead of 24.

Hi, I am following the approach as mentioned by *mu is too short* in the first answer. The issue I am having now is that instead of getting all the 24 rows to be displayed in the table, it is displaying only 23 rows and missing the 1st row data. When I am logging it in the console, it shows all 24 entries but in the table 23 rows are getting displayed.

Please suggest some solution for the same.

Thanks.

EDIT: I have been able to solve the above issue of showing 23 rows instead of 24. It might be useful for others.In the correct answer below,instead of using the i, it should have been i+1.

```
     $tr = $('#tableData table tr:eq(' + i + ')');
```

replace it by

```
     $tr = $('#tableData table tr:eq(' + (i+1) + ')');
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `success` callback from your main `$.ajax` call looks like this:

```
success: function(data) {
    var tableDataA = '<table border="0" width="500">';
    $.each(data, function(i, detail) {
        $.getJSON("webService2", function(metaData) {
            // ...
        });
    });

    tableDataA = tableDataA + '</table>';
    $('#tableData').empty();
    $('#tableData').append(tableDataA);
}
```

Each of your `$.getJSON` calls is asynchronous so the callback functions that build `tableDataA` won't be executed until some time after your `success` callback is finished. That means that when you get to the bottom of the `success` callback, you're just doing this:

```
    $('#tableData').empty();
    $('#tableData').append('<table border="0" width="500"></table>');
```

and you get an empty table. Later, when the `$.getJSON` calls finish, they will add some data to `tableDataA` but it will be too late, no one will care what's in `tableDataA` at that point.

You could replace your [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) calls with synchronous [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) calls but your users will hate you for it.

You could build the whole empty table in your `success` callback and then your `$.getJSON` callbacks would just fill in the blanks with something like this in your `success` callback:

```
var tableDataA = '<table border="0" width="500">';
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i)
    tableDataA += '<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>';
tableDataA += '</table>';
$('#tableData').empty();
$('#tableData').append(tableDataA);

$.each(data, function(i, detail) {
    $.getJSON('webService2', function(metaData) {
        $tr = $('#tableData table tr:eq(' + i + ')');
        // Fill in the table cells in $tr
    });
});
```

If possible, it would be better to merge the two services into one that would give you the whole JSON blob that you need in one go. If you don't have control over the remote systems then the above "fill in the blanks" approach might be the easiest approach.

Comment: Hi mu, thanks for the reply. I will try out this approach. I have a question regarding the table formation. Is this approach good or creating table using the array is better like in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864294/dynamic-creation-of-large-html-table-in-javascript-performance/4865247#4865247 as for a particular user might have a lot of data and the table needs to be generated in a reasonable time. The web services are out of my control and I have to work with what is given to me.

Comment: @user977815: You don't have the data when you want it so you can't do what the answer is doing. Here I build the whole empty table and then fill it in as data becomes available; you don't know what order the `getJSON` calls will return in so you want the whole table to be in place all the time so that you don't have to mess around with figuring out where things should go as the `getJSON` calls return. If you have a large table to fill then you might end up with too many `getJSON` calls for comfort, then you'd have to manage the queuing by hand (and that gets ugly).

Comment: Right now I am working on making a prototype but it might be made into a full fledged webapp. I need to built it in such a way so that it scales up for large data set too. Do you suggest using anything other than getJSON? Also I will need to perform tasks like sorting the data by a column and filtering data but that needs to be done using drop down options rather than thead approach so I can't use DataTables pluggin(or similar ones) for it.If you know of any pluggin please suggest for accomplishing the above task of sorting and filtering or it needs to be done using custom functions.

Comment: Can you please give an example of manipulating $tr and adding content to it as I am a newbie in jQuery. Thanks again.

Comment: DataTables has an API that will allow you to sort and filter from whatever elements you want. You may not have seen it during your initial research because the DT API is expansive. Based on your description, I would strongly recommend trying DataTables.

Comment: I don't know DataTables that well, maybe @gregp can help with that. You could do `$tr.find('td:eq(0)').text(metaData.title)` and such to fill in the `<tr>`, adjust the 0 to get other cells.

Comment: For larger data sets, change your server side stuff to return more than one row at a time or convince @gregp to put answer down :)

Comment: We're starting to split into two questions. ;-) If you're using DataTables, the cell manipulation is almost exactly as mu specifies, using some variables that are in the DT object. Filtering and sorting with DT isn't hard, but certainly not the domain of a Question's comment area. ;-) If you decide to go that way, I'd write new questions and tag them with 'datatables' and 'jquery'

Comment: @gregp: Thanks for the suggestion, I will try out the DataTables API. It would be helpful if you can create a new question and give some example of customizing DT Object. Although I have not tried it yet, but would like to see how to make it work on case to case basis rather than using thead example which is all over web.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some basic table tr manipulation using basic jQuery.

$('.gridNoTaxes').find('tr').each(function () {
    var totalRowCount = $('.gridNoTaxes').find("tbody tr").length;

```
var currentRowIndex = $(this)[0].rowIndex;

if ((currentRowIndex != (totalRowCount - 1)) && (currentRowIndex != 0)) {

    var priorCompID = $(this).find('td:eq(0)').children().get(0);
    var date = $(this).find('td:eq(1)').children().get(0);
    var amount = $(this).find('td:eq(2)').children().get(0);

    if (priorCompID.value.toString() == "") {
        valueString = valueString + '0' + '|';
    }
    else {
        valueString = valueString + priorCompID.value.toString() + '|';
    }

    valueString = valueString + date.value.toString() + '|';
    valueString = valueString + amount.value.toString() + '|~~';

    }
});


$('.gridNoTaxes').find('tbody')
 .append($('<tr>')
 .append($('<td>')
 .append($('<input>')
 .attr('class', 'pcID')))

 .append($('<td>')
 .append($('<input>')
 .attr('class', 'date')
 .attr('onBlur', 'HandleEvent_SimpleGrid(this)')))


 .append($('<td>')
 .append($('<input>')
 .attr('class', 'amount')
 .attr('onBlur', 'HandleEvent_SimpleGrid(this)')))

 .append($('<td>')));
```