# Fast managing of tables with ~10k rows in Javascript

Tags: javascript, performance

I've been working with tables and a huge amount of data. There are a tables in my website with 10 thousand rows. This table has dynamic search, filters, etc. I've been using pure JavaScript considering performance, but it gets laggy with this amount of rows.

Do you guys know any alternative for pure JavaScript with better performance?

EDIT> I REALLY need to load the 10 thousand rows at once. I can load them all in the browser in 5 seconds. The main problems are the filters and search...

EDIT2> The search is dynamic. I can search by name and filter it by first character.
I've been working on it for months...

SEARCH:

1. search when the field has more than 3 characters and only when its length and characters has changed (onchange event on input may trigger multiple times when a character changes, so I make sure it only triggers once using some verifications)
2. each row that matches the searched string is coppied to another table. The original table is hidden and the new one is displayed.
3. when the user changes the search field or cancel the dynamic search, the new table is erased.
4. Conclusion: it's faster to create a new table with desired elements than hide the undesired ones.

FITLER

1. The rows are actually in 25 tables (A to Z + non-alphabetical characters)
2. When you select a character, only that table is shown
3. Conclusion: it's faster to hide a whole table than hide the
   undesired rows

Thanks for the repplies. I've edited with some extra info so we can narrow the possible solutions...

Comment: You have "10 tousand rows" in the same page ? You should consider not displaying them all at the same time.

Comment: I would use a web worker if you have to keep it on the frontend, or make ajax calls and perform computations on the server

Comment: what browser are you using? are you using jQuery plugins? which one? DataTables, jTables, or jqGrid? DataTables can handle more than 11 thousand rows.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider using lazy loading

Comment: 10,000 rows? Your issue is that that is just a flat-out huge document. If you need it all on the page at the same time, it's going to be laggy, full-stop. If you don't, think about Ajax: get the filter or search query, send a request to the server, get a set of the most relevant rows, and display those on the page.

Comment: you need to lower your node count. javascript is not the problem, but it can draw 30 rows of the 10,000 rows on-demand. you wire the pagination and sort into a js model, and then render a small slice of that model instead of transforming it all into html from the get-go.

Comment: I REALLY need to load the 10 thousand rows at once. I can load them all in the browser in 5 seconds, using a POST to get the data and javascript appends. The main problem is the filter and search...

Comment: how are you performing the filter and search? perhaps something like DataTables would run faster than your hand code

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic creation of large html table in javascript performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864294/dynamic-creation-of-large-html-table-in-javascript-performance)

Answer (score 4):

I'm asuming you get the contents from database and load with with something like PHP (I'm going to asume PHP for now)

You could make the Javascript make an ajaxcall to a php-file which does the filtering (actually you should make the database do it, a lot faster!) and place the resulting table back on screen.

---

A faster method combined with the above might be this: Get all id's on the initial rows in an array and save those (in a session might work pleasant).

When you have to filter, don't make PHP get the whole table, just apply the filter to only the stored id's and send javascript the matching rows.

Then make javascript do something like this:
- set all visible
- set resulting id's to hidden (hidden in favor of remove, because I think a user might perform multiple filter actions?)

---

Another idea just popped in my head: If you don't need to display it on load, you can start the initial load with all tables hidden and a message "please search to display".

Comment: Ah, complete tables. Hiding those would be alot faster indeed. If you use some animation, I suggest you turn those off to, sliding is very slow in this amount of data

Answer (score 2):

A common technique to handle this case is to load the data in memory or a subset of the data, and recycle your table rows such that you aren't actually ever creating thousands upon thousands of rows.  You can get creative with this and create a web interface that seemingly scrolls endlessly but in reality you are just reusing dom elements and shuffling them around.

Most well-built data grid widgets whether they are on the web, mobile or even a desktop interface will employ this technique to handle your particular problem.

In most cases a user will never actually find themselves benefiting from seeing 10's of thousands of rows of data at once anyway.

Answer (score 0):

*fetch from the server only the things to be seen by the user*, Like everyone has pointed out 10,000 rows needn't be there on that page.

you can use the concept of **pagination**  and for every *page* few rows are fetched and shown . JQuery's Ajax is capable of calling the server side function to fetch rows to add them to your page.

don't know any backend details here, but in *struts framework* there is `display:table` tag and I believe in *.NET framework* there is `GridView` for pagination in the client side that you can look into

Answer (score -1):

I'm just a student, newly joined to the community. Take what I say with a grain of salt.

I'm not sure why everyone is so much as blinking at the ten thousand rows business when we're measuring modern personal computers' memory in gigabytes.

Alright. I'm going to assume that what you're doing needs to be done in the browser, and so you can't switch to doing native code. In that case, looking for an alternative to Javascript won't get you much of anywhere. In the context of a browser, you're looking at an interpreted language. In terms of number of instructions the program ultimately has to run, the difference between one language or another is negligible in the face of how long it takes to be interpreted. Besides, Javascript has gotten nicely polished over the years.

So never mind that. There's a much more important thing to consider here, and it applies no matter what you're programming in or on: The cache(s). [Igor Ostrovsky explains it beautifully](http://igoro.com/archive/gallery-of-processor-cache-effects/); read it until you grok it.

So I'm *guessing* you have objects that would stringify to something like, `"obj1 = {field-1:'a', field-2:'b', ..., field-n:'n'}"`. And you can select a `field-i` to sort by. The trouble with this is that when you sort by `field-i`, you're loading the entirety of `obj1` into the cache, even though you don't need it. What you really want to do is load the `field-i`'s for`obj1, obj2, obj3, ..., objm` all at once. So you look at an array, stringifying to something like: `"field1 = [refToRow1, field1inRow1, refToRow2, field1inRow2, ..., refToRowM, field1inRowM]"`.

You might not be able to do fit all M rows in the cache, after all `M==10000`! But you can group them together into chunks that you could reasonably expect a cache to manage. Anyone got a good number for this? Say, 64kB? So you figure for each `i` in `M` you've got a reference, and a field that's probably just a reference to a short string (it'd be better if you could have the string itself right there, but I don't think Javascript works that way). So that's 8B? 8B*1024 = 64kB? Hell, if that's right, you could fit it all into the cache in two chunks, which means you'd want to do it in 4.

So now you've got a collection of smaller arrays, and you want to sort them. This is a classic application for [B-trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree). And while having a separate B-tree for each and every column in the table may seem like a lot, it's not.

Okay, so that handles sorting. You tell it to sort by a column, and the truth is it's already sorted! You're just repopulating the visible table using a different b-tree. You still need to handle filtering, but that's fine. You do some cache juggling as you find something to display and follow the reference to get the other fields, but I'd still expect this to go fast since you're skipping over so many rows.

Normally, I would say if you want to speed things up, look into multiprocessing. But I think browsers are still working to make that a thing with their Javascript implementations. Plus, while it would be well-suited for sorting, it would be a lot of effort to make it useful for the filtering part, and I expect you can do fine without.

I hope this isn't too scatter-brained, and that it gives you some ideas. Good luck!

Comment: "I'm not sure why everyone is so much as blinking at the ten thousand rows business when we're measuring modern personal computers' memory in gigabytes": I guess they are not blinking at *managing* 10k rows, but *displaying* 10k rows at a time. It just doesn't make sense, there is no way for a user to handle all that informations at once.

Comment: It's 2016 and inserting 10k table rows into the DOM still takes a considerable amount of time, even in Chrome. With barebone Javascript you can get about a 10th of a second, but all the syles, event handlers, and everything else that gets added on top of that adds to the lag. https://jsfiddle.net/mwow3shh/